# how to run code from android studio to an emulator

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A5000 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56852/GG90J4_is8A=/ws
Syncing files to device ONEPLUS A5000...
D/emuglGLESv2_enc( 3798): GL com.example.my_new_flutter ViewportNeedFlush 0
D/EGL_emulation( 3798): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9fef1a00: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0x9de31780)
D/emuglGLESv2_enc( 3798): GL com.example.my_new_flutter ViewportNeedFlush 0
```

i don't Know what's wrong, my emulator wont run any thing, is just shows white page, please help me with it.

Comment: I'm not so sure that's an error message. whats your code? `main.dart`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of this. I hope it works out.

- Make sure that you have the latest graphics drivers installed for your computer.
- Change the OpenGL ES renderer. The emulator allows you to choose between different OpenGL ES renderers. Try changing the renderer and see if that fixes the problem.
- Reinstall the emulator. If you have tried all of the above and you are still getting a white screen, you can try reinstalling the emulator.